# Logs not being directed to error.log for a virtual host in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, logging

I have an entry in virtual hosts for apache2 as

```
ErrorLog /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log
```

The file is created at this locaiton, but logs are written to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

I am using ubuntu 10.04

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is caused by an improper Vhost config. Make sure that the requests you're sending to the server are actually being served by the vhost instead of the default apache process.

Another possibility is that apache2 wasn't restarted after adding the ErrorLog config.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am using mod wsgi for django which runs as apache child process may be that is the cause! Let me change the config and see how it behaves.

Comment: Thats it, I used  mod_wsgi daemon mode and it worked.